# Change row values till first match

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

There is a table with the following structure:
(Date, Shop, Exists, Status)

```
2012-10-09  Shop1   0   Trial
2012-10-23  Shop1   0   New
2012-10-30  Shop1   0   New
2012-11-13  Shop1   0   New
2012-11-27  Shop1   1   New
2012-12-11  Shop1   0   New
2012-12-18  Shop1   0   New
```

I need to convert it to the following result:

```
2012-10-09  Shop1   0   Trial
2012-10-23  Shop1   0   Trial
2012-10-30  Shop1   0   Trial
2012-11-13  Shop1   0   Trial
2012-11-27  Shop1   1   New
2012-12-11  Shop1   0   New
2012-12-18  Shop1   0   New
```

The algorithm is set to trial till Exists column = 1.

There are more Shops, so getting Date value (2012-11-27 in my case) for every single shop doesn't look very sane. Any clues?

Comment: Is there an order to process the rows, e.g. by `Date`?

Comment: You're right, the that's ordered by Date column.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not supposed to order the rows except in the way they are exactly in the database then when you go to get the Row Number (you need that to help you find all rows before the row that has 1 for Exists), then you use ORDER BY (SELECT 1) when using ROW_NUMBER.  It will take the rows as they are in your table and give them row numbers.

Then find the first row with 1 for Exists and store it in a variable.  You can then join the temp table that has the row numbers with your original table and do the update below.

That should do it for you!

```
SELECT '2012-10-09' AS ShopDate,  'Shop1' AS ShopName,  '0' AS ShopExists,   'Trial' AS ShopStatus  INTO #Shops UNION
SELECT '2012-10-23',  'Shop1',  '0',   'New'    UNION
SELECT '2012-10-30',  'Shop1',  '0',   'New'    UNION
SELECT '2012-11-13',  'Shop1',  '0',   'New'    UNION
SELECT '2012-11-27',  'Shop1',  '1',   'New'    UNION
SELECT '2012-12-11',  'Shop1',  '0',   'New'    UNION
SELECT '2012-12-18',  'Shop1',  '0',   'New'     


SELECT s.*
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (ShopDate)) AS RowNumber
  INTO #temp
  FROM #Shops s

SELECT *
  FROM #temp

DECLARE @RowNumber INT = (SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber FROM #temp WHERE ShopExists = 1 ORDER BY RowNumber ASC)

--SELECT *
UPDATE s  SET ShopStatus = 'Trial'
  FROM #temp t
  JOIN #Shops s
    ON s.ShopDate = t.ShopDate
   AND s.ShopName = t.ShopName
   AND s.ShopExists = t.ShopExists
   AND s.ShopStatus = t.ShopStatus
 WHERE RowNumber < @RowNumber

SELECT *
  FROM #Shops

DROP TABLE #Shops
DROP TABLE #temp
```

This was the end result:

```
ShopDate    ShopName    ShopExists  ShopStatus
2012-10-09  Shop1       0           Trial
2012-10-23  Shop1       0           Trial
2012-10-30  Shop1       0           Trial
2012-11-13  Shop1       0           Trial
2012-11-27  Shop1       1           New
2012-12-11  Shop1       0           New
2012-12-18  Shop1       0           New
```

Comment: In a recent comment the OP states that the rows should be processed in `Date` order, hence you ought to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS RowNumber`. Using `OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` (or the popular `select NULL` variation) does _not_ provide any guarantee of row order. If you believe otherwise, please add a citation of the appropriate documentation.

Comment: Ah, this was already up before that comment had been made.  But I have amended my code to reflect that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the 'New' rows before the first ShopExists date using the query below. It includes the date the shop first existed as the last column. You should be able to use the results to update your table accordingly.

```
select 
    s1.*, s2.FirstExistsDate 
from 
    Shops s1
inner join 
    ( select s.ShopName, MIN(ShopDate) as FirstExistsDate 
      from Shops s
      where ShopExists = 1
      group by s.ShopName
    ) s2 on s1.ShopName = s2.ShopName and s1.ShopDate < s2.FirstExistsDate and s1.ShopStatus = 'New'
```